# How to convert string in value to attributes and values?

Tags: r, dataframe, gis, openstreetmap

I have 3mio observations with the attribute "other_tags". The value of "other_tags" have to be converted to new attributes and values.

dput()

```
structure(list(osm_id = c(105093, 107975, 373652), other_tags = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("\"addr:city\"=>\"Neuenegg\",\"addr:street\"=>\"Stuberweg\",\"building\"=>\"school\",\"building:levels\"=>\"2\"", 
"\"building\"=>\"commercial\",\"name\"=>\"Pollahof\",\"type\"=>\"multipolygon\"", 
"\"building\"=>\"yes\",\"amenity\"=>\"sport\",\"type\"=>\"multipolygon\""
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Here is a subsample of the data:

```
osm_id  other_tags
105093  "building"=>"commercial","name"=>"Pollahof","type"=>"multipolygon"
107975  "building"=>"yes","amenity"=>"sport","type"=>"multipolygon"
373652  "addr:city"=>"Neuenegg","addr:street"=>"Stuberweg","building"=>"school","building:levels"=>"2"
```

This is the desired data format: Make new attributes (only for building and amenity) and add the value.

```
osm_id  building    amenity
105093  commercial
107975  yes         sport
373652  school
```

Thx for your help!

Comment: You need to define **rules** for the sought extractions: by what rule can, for example, the value `sport` be detected in the strings? ALso post a minimal reproducible data sample with `dput()`.

Comment: hi christ, the amenity is included in the second row (edited). So there is no rule. Just if the amenity is present, it should make the column "amenity" and the value. I also added the data sample with dput

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that difficult.

- `other_tags` is factor column, so we have to use `as.charachter` on that
- Extract results in an intermediate list say `s` where all variable are separated; after splitting these from `split = ','` using `strsplit`
- store these attributes in a seaparte rwo for each attribute in anew dataframe say `df2`
- use `separate()` from `tidyr` to break attributae name and value in two separate columns.  separator `sep` is used as `=>` this time
- remove extra quotation marks by using `str_remove_all`
- optionally `filter` the dataset
- `pivot_wider` into the desired format.

```
library(tidyverse)

s <- strsplit(as.character(df$other_tags), split = ",")

df2 <- data.frame(osm_id = rep(df$osm_id, sapply(s, length)), other_tags = unlist(s))

df2 %>% separate(other_tags, into = c("Col1", "Col2"), sep = "=>") %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Col"), ~str_remove_all(., '"'))) %>%
  filter(Col1 %in% c("amenity", "building")) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = osm_id, names_from = Col1, values_from = Col2)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  osm_id building   amenity
   <dbl> <chr>      <chr>  
1 105093 commercial NA     
2 107975 yes        sport  
3 373652 school     NA
```

If however, filter is not used

```
df2 %>% separate(other_tags, into = c("Col1", "Col2"), sep = "=>") %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Col"), ~str_remove_all(., '"'))) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = osm_id, names_from = Col1, values_from = Col2)

# A tibble: 3 x 8
  osm_id building   name     type         amenity `addr:city` `addr:street` `building:levels`
   <dbl> <chr>      <chr>    <chr>        <chr>   <chr>       <chr>         <chr>            
1 105093 commercial Pollahof multipolygon NA      NA          NA            NA               
2 107975 yes        NA       multipolygon sport   NA          NA            NA               
3 373652 school     NA       NA           NA      Neuenegg    Stuberweg     2
```

A single pipe syntax

```
df %>% mutate(other_tags = as.character(other_tags),
              other_tags = str_split(other_tags, ",")) %>%
  unnest(other_tags) %>%
  mutate(other_tags = str_remove_all(other_tags, '"')) %>%
  separate(other_tags, into = c("Col1", "Col2"), sep = "=>") %>%
  filter(Col1 %in% c("amenity", "building")) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = osm_id, names_from = Col1, values_from = Col2)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  osm_id building   amenity
   <dbl> <chr>      <chr>  
1 105093 commercial NA     
2 107975 yes        sport  
3 373652 school     NA
```

Comment: thx this worked! the single pipe syntax is top.

Answer (score -1):

We can use `(g)sub` and `str_extract` as well as lookaround (in just two lines of code):

```
library(stringr)
df$building <- str_extract(gsub('"','', df$other_tags),'(?<=building=>)\\w+(?=,)')
df$amenity <- str_extract(gsub('"','', df$other_tags),'(?<=amenity=>)\\w+(?=,)')
```

If for some reason you want to remove column `other_tags`:

```
df$other_tags <- NULL
```

Result:

```
df
  osm_id   building amenity
1 105093 commercial    <NA>
2 107975        yes   sport
3 373652     school    <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks for saying thanks. I frankly don't understand why a rather convoluted solution is preferred over a transparent economical one...

Comment: Maybe that's because your answer does not really produce the desired output and works only for the mini example, not for the general case...

Comment: How do you know it does not work fo the general case? And that it doesn't produce the desired output is laughable ... If OP for some reason cannot by any means keep the original column then they just have to set it to `NULL`!